# How to create a bash file to search filenames and exec command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, script

I am trying to create a bash file to search several filename parts and record those parts to add as a parameter in a command, who will be getmail. After testing it at file location, it was working well, but when i tried to execute that bash from outside folders, through,

```
 ~/.getmail/checkmail.sh
```

I received this error that i dont understand because it is in the right folder but dont know why is not searching, because the location in the error is the right one,

```
remote:~ Xserver$ ~/.getmail/checkmail.sh
MAIL ENTRANCE AT:
DATE: 11/11/16 TIME: 09:26:33
Error: configuration file /Users/Xserver/.getmail/getmailrc_* does not exist
```

Files in that directory:

```
remote:Users Xserver$ ls /Users/Xserver/.getmail/
checkmail.sh                        logs
getmailrc_teste                     
getmailrc_teste2
```

Privileges from outside:

```
drwx------   8 Xserver  staff    272 11 Nov 09:07 .getmail
```

Privileges from inside:

```
-rwx------   1 Xserver  staff   394 11 Nov 09:50 checkmail.sh
-rw-r--r--   1 root           staff   313 10 Nov 15:44 getmailrc_teste
-rw-r--r--   1 Xserver  staff   316 10 Nov 15:44 getmailrc_teste2
drwxr-xr-x   4 Xserver  staff   136 10 Nov 17:15 logs
```

My system is an UNIX and here you have my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#bash created to load every single getmailrc file per email account

echo "MAIL ENTRANCE AT:"
date "+DATE: %m/%d/%y TIME: %H:%M:%S"

RCARGS=""

#adds all rcfiles in one single line to execute in the last line with getmail
for F in getmailrc_*; do
        RCARGS="$RCARGS --rcfile $F"  # prepares the --rcfile args for getmail
done

exec getmail $RCARGS
```

I know that this could be a noob problem, but i am a bit rusty with scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a location problem, and i solve it by adding just a cd ~/.getmail/ until it starts searching.